Induction following the scheme of Fixpoint
In Coq.Lists.List we have
  Fixpoint nth (n:nat) (l:list A) (default:A) {struct l} : A :=
    match n, l with
      | O, x :: l' => x
      | O, [] => default
      | S m, [] => default
      | S m, x :: t => nth m t default
    end.

We define nth_ok_prop with
Fixpoint nth_ok_prop (n:nat) (l:list A) (default:A) {struct l} : Prop :=
  match n, l with
    | O, x :: l' => True
    | O, [] => False
    | S m, [] => False
    | S m, x :: t => nth_ok_prop m t default
  end.

I'd like to prove
Lemma nth_out_range : forall n l,
  ~ nth_ok_prop n l default -> nth n l default = default.

and if possible, with an induction following the scheme of the two Fixpoints, which would make it trivial.
Is it possible?

Please tell us what you have already attempted so far, and where you are stuck.

Equation generates induction schemes. So does Function.

@JoJo: maybe later, I'm not at home roght now.

@Zlotz just fyi, your problem is routinely solvable, but it's the concepts behind this that matter. Writing a good explanation about how and why is hard if I do not know where you're at and what you need explained. Hence asking for what you have done so far already.

As far as I know, there is no plugin to generate functional elimination from an existing definition. But you can write new definitions and get functional elimination automatically using the package Equations.
Require Import List. Import ListNotations.
From Equations Require Import Equations.

Section Foo.

  Context {A : Type}.

  Equations nth (n:nat) (l:list A) (default:A) : A :=
  | O, x :: l' ,default := x
  | O, [] ,default := default
  | S m, [] ,default := default
  | S m, x :: t , default := nth m t default.

Fixpoint nth_ok_prop (n:nat) (l:list A) (default:A) {struct l} : Prop :=
  match n, l with
    | O, x :: l' => True
    | O, [] => False
    | S m, [] => False
    | S m, x :: t => nth_ok_prop m t default
  end.

  Lemma nth_out_range : forall n l default,
    ~ nth_ok_prop n l default -> nth n l default = default.
  Proof.
    intros n l default. funelim (nth n l default).
    all : simp nth; cbn.
    all : try reflexivity; try contradiction.
  Qed.

If your definition is complicated enough to need functional elimination, (wf rec, non-structural rec, etc...) then it can really be worth it, even if it means reproving a few lemmas.
You can also prove it by hand for a particular definition but that can be very painful, and annoying to use after
Require Import List. Import ListNotations.
From Equations Require Import Equations.

Section Foo.

  Context {A : Type}.

  Fixpoint nth (n:nat) (l:list A) (default:A) : A :=
  match n, l with
  | O, [] => default
  | O, x :: l' => x
  | S m, [] => default
  | S m, x :: t => nth m t default
  end.

Definition FunctionalElimination_nth :
  (forall P : nat -> list A -> A -> A -> Type,
  (forall default : A,
      P 0 [] default default) ->
  (forall (x : A) (l' : list A) (default : A),
      P 0 (x :: l') default x) ->
  (forall (m : nat) (default : A),
      P (S m) [] default default) ->
  (forall (m : nat) (x : A) (t : list A) (default : A),
      P m t default (nth m t default) ->
      P (S m) (x :: t) default (nth m t default)) ->
  forall (n : nat) (l : list A) (default : A),
      P n l default (nth n l default)).
Proof.
  intros P P0nil P0cons PSnil PScons.
  intros n; induction n; intros l; induction l; intros default; cbn.
  - apply P0nil.
  - apply P0cons.
  - apply PSnil.
  - apply PScons. apply IHn.
Defined.

Fixpoint nth_ok_prop (n:nat) (l:list A) (default:A) {struct l} : Prop :=
  match n, l with
    | O, x :: l' => True
    | O, [] => False
    | S m, [] => False
    | S m, x :: t => nth_ok_prop m t default
  end.

Lemma nth_out_range : forall n l default,
  ~ nth_ok_prop n l default -> nth n l default = default.
Proof.
  intros n l default. pattern n, l, default.
  apply FunctionalElimination_nth with
   (P:= fun n l default x => ~ nth_ok_prop n l default -> x = default); cbn.
  all : try reflexivity; try contradiction.
  eauto.
Qed.
```


Proving your theorem is routine, and to be honest deriving a custom functional induction scheme in this case seems like "overkill" since the theorem is easily provable without.
The first thing to note is that what you think to be the "scheme of a Fixpoint" is not what this actually is, when limiting oneself to Coq's actual type theory. What is happening here is that your fixpoints are defined by structural recursion on the argument l : list A.
This is apparent from the fact that you have {struct l} in the definition.
This means that all theorems about these functions should be proven by induction on l. And indeed, your theorem is provable by induction on l.
What complicates things a little is that your recursive functions also modifiy other variables throughout the recursion, in particular, n. Unlike default, which stays constant throughout the recursion, the value of n changes from one recursive call to the next. Thus, the default strategy of proving the goal with intros n l. induction l. fails because Coq infers the wrong induction motive. You need to tell Coq that it n should be quantified in the inductive hypothesis, so that you are actually proving the statement forall n, ... by induction on l. The beginner way of doing this is revert n, induction l; intros n; the more advanced way is writing induction l in n|-*. Either way, this strengthens the inductive hypothesis so that it is proven for all n, not just for a fixed n. In other words, it allows n to change throughout the recursion.
Once you do that, you will notice that the proof goes through. Of course, you still need to do a case analysis on n, but that should not be difficult.
We thus get the following proof:
Lemma nth_out_range : forall n l,
  ~ nth_ok_prop n l default -> nth n l default = default.
Proof.
  intros n l.
  revert n; induction l as [|x lr IH]; intros n.
  (* alternative for the above line: [induction l as [|x lr IH] in n|-*] *)
  - now destruct n.
  - destruct n; simpl.
    + tauto.
    + apply IH.
Qed.  


There is also generalize which is strictly more powerful than revert (works with arbitrary expressions), and, more to the point, generalize dependent, which takes care of dependent hypotheses.  Indeed, the latter is presented and used throughout in SF/LF.

@jojomodding what you say "al theorems about these functons can be proved with induction" is probably true, but for some functions this is not so trivial. e.g. for div2 the proofs by induction are less trivial to perform. This is because the default induction principles generated by Rocq for an inductive type are less flexible than the full fix+match. Even for structural recursion.

Note that I said "should" because it's a suggestion for how to go about things, not a statement about metatheory. @PierreCourtieu

OK. A great thanks to Pierre who put me on the right track.
Sorry Thomas, I saw your answer when I arrived to post mine, which has still another approach.
I use functional induction:
From Coq Require Import Lists.List.
From Coq Require Import FunInd.

Import ListNotations.

Context {A : Type}.
Context {default : A}.

Lemma nth_offset_1 : forall k l a,
  nth (S k) (a::l) default = nth k l default.
Proof.
  auto.
Qed.

Function nth_ok_prop (n:nat) (l:list A) (default:A) : Prop :=
  match n, l with
    | O, x :: l' => True
    | O, [] => False
    | S m, [] => False
    | S m, x :: t => nth_ok_prop m t default
  end.

Lemma nth_out_range : forall n l,
  ~ nth_ok_prop n l default -> nth n l default = default.
Proof.
  intro.
  intro.
  functional induction (nth_ok_prop n l default) using nth_ok_prop_ind.
  - tauto.
  - auto.
  - auto.
  - intro.
    unshelve epose proof (IHP _) as H1.
    tauto.
    assert (forall k l a,
      nth (S k) (a::l) default = nth k l default
    ).
    apply nth_offset_1.
    pose proof (H0 m t x).
    auto.
Qed.

If someone knows a way to avoid the ugly assert and directly use nth_offset_1 with adequate values, I'm interested.

(IMO) You are doing things that make little sense (not even the intent is clear, which is why I won't clean that up), plus with tools that denote that you don't know much of what is available in Coq and for what...  My advice (again? I might have said it already) is go through at least LF in the Software Foundations series: these dependently-typed languages are the most complex and difficult of the whole spectrum, and with just trial and error or the casual exploration one stays at the same stage forever even in Python...

I agree with Julio. You should consider doing a bit of Software Foundations or sth because the code seems to indicate that you do not really understand how reasoning on recursive definitions work. Note, it can be fast if you already have basics and just need a bit more understanding: you do not need to do everything

I personally do not know how FunInd works, I have actually never heard of it. A question is then does it scale and combine with complicated features like wf-rec. Be aware that it may not, which Equations basically does.

@Julio: OK, is there an easier to grasp proof assistant than Coq?

My short answer to someone coming from programming, as opposed to mathematics or (theoretical) CS, would be no: AFAICT (after a couple of years exploring PAs), Coq+SF is a great if not the the best way to get started... with learning the whole dependently-typed programming thing, not just this or that tool, up to learning how to formalize things to begin with, aka from programming to applied formal logic proper.  --  Here is an even gentler introduction: Software Foundations in Coq by M.R. Clarkson (YouTube)

OK I work on it. I'm graduated in math.

BTW, there is also an FStar that I like a lot as it is cut out for the programmer, indeed simpler than the typical PA, but then I got stuck on the simplest tutorial problems, as guessing hypotheses for the Z3 solver is plain magic to me: but that might be me and I have not insisted much...  --  P.S.  I see: maybe I should have said depending on where you are heading to, not where you are coming from.  :)  If you are only interested in PAs as tools for mathematics, then I wouldn't know what to suggest.

I'm trying to formalize stuff in the theory of social choice (things like https://github.com/tchajed/coq-arrows-theorem)

Yeah: I said many words above, but the main overall thing is just that: you want to go verified-formal (not just "formal on paper"), you need to learn concrete formal logic.  -- I'll stop there, so much could be said and discussed, and more precisely, just not in these comments.

@JulioDiEgidio can you say something more concrete? What is bad about this Coq proof? All I can see is that you are judging people's personal capabilities.

@ice1000  Besides that I can't guess how you surmise I frame anyone when I have rather been making explicit who I am talking to/for, understanding each other is part of the communication, hopefully collaboration, game, especially when the game in question is learning: so not even in abstract you'd have a valid point.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@ThomasLamiaux the answer is no funind is slowly bit roting and Equation + funelim is the recommended way of doing this. Hopefully eventually functional scheme will be refactored to use Equation backend.

For the record the Functional Scheme command is able to generate such principles from an existing definition, although it is currently deprecated (and bugged).
As said in a previous answer in your case you can perform the induction directly with induction l and then destruct n but in general this is not always so simple (although possible). See e.g. this common question.
Require Import FunInd.
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Functional Scheme nth_ind := Induction for nth Sort Prop.

Fixpoint nth_ok_prop {A:Type} (n:nat) (l:list A) (default:A) {struct l} : Prop :=
  match n, l with
    | O, x :: l' => True
    | O, [] => False
    | S m, [] => False
    | S m, x :: t => nth_ok_prop m t default
  end.

Lemma nth_out_range : forall A (default:A) n l,
  ~ nth_ok_prop n l default -> nth n l default = default.
  intros A def n l . 
  functional induction (nth n l def);intros;cbn in H;auto.
  - exfalso. apply H;auto.
Qed.

